# this becomes null when retrieving regular class instances from vuex store

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a simple ES6 class instance:

```
class Element {
 constructor() {
  this.selected = false;
 }

 select() {
  this.selected = true;
 }

 unselect() {
  this.selected = false;
 }
}
```

I instantiate it and then save it in vuex store in an array of `elements` and later retrieve it and output it inside a vue template:

[image]

However, inside the mouse down event, if I do something like this in my method:

```
select() {
console.log(this); // null
  this.selected = true;
 }
```

and, the unselect method does not fire at all.

How do I retain/reinstate access to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the function reference directly as the event listener and so it won't be called on the `element` instance as expected.

You should write the function call directly within the attribute like this:

```
@mousedown="element.select()"
@mouseup="element.unselect()"
```

That way you know for certain the `element` instance will be `this`.

---

Let me clarify something that's worth mentioning in case it isn't clear, because there's some unexplained magic happening here. Vue will wrap the `v-on` value in a function if the expression evaluates to a function call or some other expression that is not a simple property accessor.

```
@event="handler"         = handler
@event="handler('foo')"  = $event => handler('foo')
@event="handler($event)" = $event => handler($event)
@event="foo.bar"         = foo.bar
@event="foo.bar('bar')"  = $event => foo.bar('bar')
@event="count++"         = $event => count++
```

So now you can see why it is necessary to call the function as in `@mousedown="event.select()"`.

The generated render function is wrapped in a [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) statement so that only `handler` is necessary instead of `this.handler`.

Lastly, read up on the purpose of [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) and how [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) works. There a plethora of information about these topics on Stack Overflow already.